# Which is faster, a regexp search or array search?

Tags: php, regex, arrays

Which is the faster:

1. a regexp to search the contents of a large file for specific pattern, or
2. an `array_search` to search a large array to match value at any index.

Comment: Those are two completely different tasks. Apples to apples, oranges to oranges...

Comment: O_o When you tested it, which one was faster?!?

Comment: Well i am doing a project in which i need to choose from these two options to maintain the response time. The file will be a ini file

Comment: What if you race (1) a search in an array of primitives against a complex regex with lots of backtracking, and (2) a search in an array of objects with very complex equality operations against a trivial regex?

Comment: One can collect ini file content in an array using parse_ini_file in that scenario

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771092/is-method-a-faster-than-method-b

Comment: Reading the file, placing it in array, searching the file -vs- Reading the file, searching the file. Seems obvious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

other things being equal, I would expect the array search to always be faster, not having to read a file and not having to parse and execute a regex.

Comment: You should give him the answer, that way people will continue to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the type of data you have, the type of data you are searching for, and the amount. You really need to try it and find which works for you, there isn't really a right answer any of us can give you without knowing the context and specific implementations.

Take a look at the [benchmark](http://pear.php.net/package/Benchmark/redirected) class if you want to see some metrics and figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Louis for the help i will try that